# Height/Length generator in feet?

Tags: javascript, html, generator

I currently have this piece of code, which is to determine a height and wingspan from a given length. I'd really like for the results to be input as a measurement of feet and inches, and the resulting wingspan and height to respond in the same measurements. I don't mind if it uses apostrophises or periods.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="LiveScript">
    function wings(form) {
        form.wingspan.value = (form.length.value * .75) * 2
        form.height.value = form.length.value * .5
    }
</SCRIPT>

<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>Dragon Length:</TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="length" SIZE=15 /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Dragon Wingspan:</TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="wingspan" SIZE=15 /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Dragon Height:</TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="height" SIZE=15 /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" ONCLICK="wings(this.form)" /></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

</FORM>
```

Comment: Your code was invalid, I edited it and added 2 missings `<TR>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading this in your browser?

If you are, then LiveScript will not run in most cases. You probably want to look at programming using Javascript or JQuery instead.

Here's a snippet to get you started, with inline comments for explanation. Note I don't actually calculate anything for you... you should try doing that on your own as practice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- You need this line so you can load the JQuery functions that you will be using -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="wings">
<TABLE>
<TR><TD>Dragon Length:</TD><TD>
    <INPUT TYPE ="text" id="winglength" SIZE=15</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</form>

<!-- ID of this element is called "trigger" and will be used for clicking -->
<div id="trigger">Click me to calculate the Wingspan and Height!</div>

<!-- This div tag is called "wingspan" -->
<div id="wingspan">Wingspan is: </div>

<!-- Can you write the HTML code for "height" here? -->

<script>

    // Everything in here will run when your page is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // When you click on the DIV tag called "trigger", you run this cod below.
        $("#trigger").click(function() {

            // "append" the wing length to the HTML tag above: the # refers to id called winglength
            $("#wingspan").append($("#winglength").val());

            // How you calculate the "height" is left as an exercise for the original poaster!
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running it on a forum, so it is just plugged into one of the posts. I'm not sure if that changes anything - as I said, I'm very newbie.

Comment: What forum? It might affect things - many forums don't allow you to run code on them.

Comment: Simple Machines; you can see that above and another one in [link](http://katila.second-pass.net/index.php?topic=2649.msg12270#msg12270). They don't read out feet and inches, though, which is what I'm after :)

Comment: Did you write the posts that you linked in these examples? As I mentioned, many forums don't allow you to write code on them. You might want to talk to the forum administrators and ask them specifics about what forms you're allowed to write. (Side note: I used to roleplay the Dragonriders of Pern many, many decades ago. ;) )

Comment: I'm the administrator of the forum, those posts are mine. Admin are the only one with the capability to post HTML as screwing it up can kill the boards. :)

Sweet! Pern is the best XD

Answer (score 0):

With no plugins or libraries, here is your example working...

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BtC4K/

**Javascript:**

```
function wings(){
    var lenght = document.getElementsByName("length")[0];
    var wingspan = document.getElementsByName("wingspan")[0];
    var height = document.getElementsByName("height")[0];

    wingspan.value = (lenght.value * 0.75) * 2;
    height.value = lenght.value * 0.5;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Dragon Length:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="length" SIZE=15 /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dragon Wingspan:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wingspan" SIZE=15 readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dragon Height:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="height" SIZE=15 readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="wings()">Calculate</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```